# how to cut string with two regular expression "_" and "."

Tags: java, string, split

i have a string like this `test_1.doc` and i want to split this string to have `1.doc`

Comment: The standard library is your friend. Try the method `String.split()`.

Comment: I think you will need to clarify the question slightly. If you do `"test_1.doc".split("_")` you can take the second element which will be `"1.doc"`. Alternatively you can just use `indexOf` to find the position of the `"_"` and then take a substring - no need for regexps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
str.split("_")[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Always consult the API for this kind of things. `String` would be a good place to start, and `split` is a good keyword to look for, and indeed, you'll find this:

[`public String[] split(String regex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29): Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "a b c".split(" ")
    )); // prints "[a, b, c]"

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "a_b_c".split("_")
    )); // prints "[a, b, c]"
```

Do keep in mind that regex metacharacters (such as dot `.`) may need to be escaped:

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "a.b.c".split(".")
    )); // prints "[]"
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "a.b.c".split("\\.")
    )); // prints "[a, b, c]"
```

Here's an example of accessing individual parts of the returned `String[]`:

```
    String[] parts = "abc_def.ghi".split("_");
    System.out.println(parts[1]); // prints "def.ghi"
```

As for what you want, it's not clear, but it may be something like this:

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "abc_def.ghi".split("[._]")
    )); // prints "[abc, def, ghi]"
```

It's also possible that you're interested in the limited split:

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "abc_def_ghi.txt".split("_", 2)
    )); // prints "[abc, def_ghi.txt]"
```

Yet another possibility is that you want to split on the last `_`. You can still do this with regex, but it's much simpler to use `lastIndexOf` instead:

```
    String filename = "company_secret_128517.doc";
    final int k = filename.lastIndexOf('_');
    String head = filename.substring(0, k);
    String tail = filename.substring(k+1);
    System.out.printf("[%s] [%s]", head, tail);
    // prints "[company_secret] [128517.doc]"
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.split("[_.]")` will split on both criteria. I'm not sure why the title of your question and its body differ though...

Comment: `[_|.]` matches `_`, `|`, or `.`; to match and underscore or a dot you would use `[_.]`.  However, the OP is only trying to split on the underscore.

Comment: My bad, I never got used to Java's sick notion of regular expressions. And was wondering why I didn't need to escape the . :-) As for the question - I got fooled by the title...

Comment: I do this and I get only 2 values in the array "test" and "1" shouldn't it be 3 in length with the third being "doc"?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean? You can just do this:

```
String s = "test_1.doc";
String[] result = s.split("_");
```

`result` will then contain two elements containing "test" and "1.doc".