# Cutting String java

Tags: java, string, split

I need to cut certain strings for an algorithm I am making. I am using `substring()` but it gets too complicated with it and actually doesn't work correctly. I found this topic [how to cut string with two regular expression "_" and "."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911005/how-to-cut-string-with-two-regular-expression-and)

and decided to try with `split()` but it always gives me

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+
^
```

So this is the code I have:

```
     String[] result = "234*(4-5)+56".split("+");
      /*for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println(result[i]);
      }*/
      Arrays.toString(result);
```

Any ideas why I get this irritating exception ?

**P.S. If I fix this I will post you the algorithm for cutting and then the algorithm for the whole calculator (because I am building a calculator). It is gonna be a really badass calculator, I promise :P**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` in regex has a special meaning. to be treated as a normal character, you should escape it with backslash.

```
  String[] result = "234*(4-5)+56".split("\\+");
```

Below are the metacharaters in regex. to treat any of them as normal characters you should escape them with backslash

```
 <([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>
```

[refer here about how characters work in regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html).

Answer (score 2):

`+` is a regex quantifier (meaning *one or more of*) so needs to be escaped in the `split` method:

```
String[] result = "234*(4-5)+56".split("\\+");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should split your string like this: -

```
String[] result = "234*(4-5)+56".split("[+]");
```

Since, `String.split` takes a `regex` as delimiter, and `+` is a meta-character in regex, which means match `1 or more` repetition, so it's an error to use it `bare` in regex.

You can use it in character class to match `+` literal. Because in `character class`, meta-characters and all other characters loose their special meaning. Only `hiephen(-)` has a special meaning in it, which means a `range`.

Answer (score 2):

The plus `+` symbol has meaning in regular expression, which is how `split` parses it's parameter.  You'll need to regex-escape the plus character.

```
.split("\\+");
```